# Get file metadata in Linux

Tags: linux, fonts

I have a script on my server that parses fonts so I can use them in my application.

Sadly, a lot of times the name of the font file itself is wrong (e.g., the file may be named _FONT1.ttf). On windows however, when i open up the file's properties, I see that inside the fonts Details tab (i.e., its metadata) the correct name is stored in a field called 'Title'.

How would I extract this piece of metadata from my file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `fc-query` utility provided as part of [`fontconfig`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig) to get the information. `fc-query` on the .ttf file will provide you with lot of information. The information which you need can be obtained by getting the fullname of the ttf file. You can try `fc-query <.ttf file> --format=%{fullname}` `man fc-query` will give you more details regarding the same.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Also, `--format=%{fullname}\\n` should add a newline after it, and adding `| tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9 \n'` to the end should remove non-alphanumerics.

Answer (score 1):

You would use [FreeType](http://www.freetype.org/) to [load the font](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html) and then look at the [`family_name` member](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_FaceRec) of the [loaded face](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Face).